# I set a callback that in return trigger a loop reaction and I cant see why?

Tags: reactjs, callback

I learn Reactjs and now I have a `loop` going on and can't figure out why. Program run but laptop get warmer and warmer and I set breakpoints and see that the code is running many times..

I have two Reactjs `Components` and I create a callback `onSetMasonryHeight()`and send it into the child Component.

The child send back result like this:

```
 ---
    this.list = React.createRef();
    
    componentDidMount() {
    const { onSetMasonryHeight } = this.props;
     setTimeout(() => {
        onSetMasonryHeight(this.list.current.clientHeight);
     }, 50);
   }
  ---
```

This work I get the `clientHeight` but this only runs once hence the `componentDidMount()`

So I do the same in: `componentDidUpdate()` because after every `render()` I need the `clientHeight`

```
...
      componentDidUpdate() {
        const { onSetMasonryHeight } = this.props;
        setTimeout(() => {
            onSetMasonryHeight(this.list.current.clientHeight);
        }, 50);
      }
...
```

And in parent `Component` I set this `clientHeight` value

```
---
    onSetMasonryHeight = val => {
        this.setState(() => {
            return { masonryHeight: val };
        });
    };
...
```

Now the loop is running but the strange thing is that app working and I can see the `clientHeight` value is the expected value but laptop get warmer and warmer my God I must pull the plugg lol.

I debug with breakpoint and I see the `render()` is triggered on both mother and child in a loop and it looks like the parent method `onSetMasonryHeight = val => {..`that has a `return` is triggering the `setState()` `render()` on the child also and this creates the loop.

Any ide? Or how can I do this better maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change you componentDidUpdate to this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.masonryHeight !== this.state.masonryHeight) {
  const { onSetMasonryHeight } = this.props;
    setTimeout(() => {
        onSetMasonryHeight(this.list.current.clientHeight);
    }, 50);
 }
}
```

- you have to check the if the state change happened before calling setState other wise you get infinite state update which gives hell for your laptop